# Exam question on fixed point iteration

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

I am solving the following exam problem.

**Problem:** An iterative scheme is given by $$ x_{n+1}= \frac{1}{5}\left(16-\frac{12}{x_n} \right).$$ Such a scheme with suitable initial approximation $x_0$ will

(a) not converge
(b) converge to $1.6$
(c) converge to $1.8$
(d) converge to $2$

**My attempt.** By defining $g(x) = 1/5(16-12/x )$, I found that fixed points of $g(x)$ are $2$ and $6/5$. Thus, given iterative scheme will converge either to $2$ or $6/5$.

Using fixed point theorem I need to find the interval [a, b] show that $g(x)\in [a, b]$ and is continuous and derivative of g(x) should exit on $(a, b)$. Further I have to check that $|g^{'}(x)| \leq r$, $r <1$.

**First confusion**: I want to know that how to find such interval $[a, b]$ satisfying these conditions?

**Second confusion:** Here we see that at fixed point $2$, $|g^{'}(2)| <1$. My confusion is then can we conclude that sequence $x_n$ will converge to $2$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Fixed point iteration is guaranteed to converge on an interval [a,b] if $max(|g'(b)|,| g'(a) | ) < 1 $. So if you are not given an interval [a,b], pick one that satisfies the above.

Comment: @CivilSigma How can convergence not depend on the derivative away from the endpoints?  What if $g(x) = a + (x-b)^2$ near $x=b$ and $g(x) = b + (x-a)^2$ near $x=a$?  Then fixed point iteration oscillates between $a$ and $b$ and never converges, but the derivative is zero at the endpoints.

Comment: @ErickWong Do you mean that the root is near $x=b$ for $g(x)=a + (x-b)^2 $ , then we pick an interval, say , $[b-3, b+3]$ and iterate to find b. I don't get what you meant by defining two functions, do we seek the point of intersection as the root we want to find?

Comment: @CivilSigma I was defining just one function (in a small neighbourhood of $b$, $g(x)$ acts like one function, and in a small neighbourhood of $a$ it acts like the other function, and in between it could behave arbitrarily).  My point is that such a function clearly satisfies $\max(|g'(b)|,|g'(a)|) < 1$ but fixed point iteration does not converge.  I guess I should have written $b - (x-a)^2$ near $x=a$ so that the counterexample doesn't take values outside of $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function
$$g(x):={1\over5}\left(16-{12\over x}\right)$$
has the fixed points $2$ and ${5\over6}$. As
$$g'(x)={12\over 5x^2}\tag{1}$$ we have
$$\bigl|g'(2)\bigr|={3\over5}<1,\qquad \bigl|g'(5/6)\bigr|={5\over3}>1\ .$$
Therefore we try to prove that $2$ is an attractive fixed point. To this end we have to produce an open $x$-interval $J$ containing $2$, and an $r<1$ such that $\bigl|g'(x)\bigr|\leq r$ for all  $x\in J$. Now from $(1)$ we obtain
$$0<g'(x)\leq {12\over 5\cdot 1.6^2}={15\over16}<1\qquad(x\geq1.6
)\ .\tag{2}$$
This shows that we can take $J:=[1.6, \>\infty[\ $ and $r={15\over16}$.

*Claim:* When $x_n\in J$ then $$|x_{n+1}-2|\leq{15\over16}\>|x_n-2|\ .$$
This implies that we can take any point $x_0\in J$ as starting point, and obtain $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=2$.

*Proof:* By the MVT there  is a point $\xi$ between $2$ and $x_n$ such that
$$|x_{n+1}-2|=\bigl|g(x_n)-g(2)\bigr|=\bigl|g'(\xi)\bigr|\>|x_n-2|\>\leq{15\over16}|x_n-2|\ ,$$
where we have made use of $(2)$, since $\xi\in J$.

Note that $g$ is a Moebius transformation with the two fixed points $2$ and ${5\over6}$. Introducing a new complex coordinate $z$ such that the two fixed points correpond to $z=0$ and $z=\infty$ "conjugates" $g$ into
$$\hat g(z)={3\over5} z\qquad(z\in\bar{\mathbb C})\ .$$
From this we can conclude that any starting point $z_0\ne\infty$, resp. $x_0\ne{5\over6}$, will lead to the desired convergence.

Comment: Thank you for a very nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Think $\{x_n\}$ as a sequence.

$$x_{n+1}-x_n=-\frac{(x_n-2)(5x_n-6)}{5x_n}$$

When $x_n>2$ then clearly $x_{n+1}-x_n<0$ (check!), and when $x_n<6/5$ then also $x_{n+1}-x_n<0$ (check!). So the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is monotone decreasing , also it is bounded (check!). So it **must be convergent**. So your option (A) is **incorrect**.

Let, $\{x_n\}$ converges to $l$. Then,

$$l=\frac{1}{5}\left(16-\frac{12}{l}\right)$$From here, you will get either $l=2$ or $l=1.2$.

**From your options** , clearly (D) is correct.

### **NOTE:**

If **'converges to $2$'** and **'converges to $1.2$'** both options are given , then  it is hard to detect that at which point it converges..In that case , it depends on the initial approximation $x_0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it not necessary to check monotonicity  of $x_n$ in the interval  $(6/5, 2)$? Please clear my doubt.

Comment: Actually when $x_0>2$ then $\{x_n\}$ is strictly decreasing ..and when $x_0<6/5$ then $\{x_n\}$ is also strictly decreasing..You can easily show it...If NOt then tell me..I will improve the answer...

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 Since $|g'(1.2)| = \tfrac53 > 1$, the fixed point at $1.2$ is repelling.

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate $g'(x)=\frac{12}{5x^2}$ so 
$$
g'(x)<1 \qquad \iff x>\sqrt{\frac{12}{5}}
$$
In particular if you take $[a,b]=[1,6 ; 3]$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_{n} =\dfrac 6 5 +\dfrac 4 {5y_{n}}$

Then the equation turns into $5y_{n+1}-3y_{n}-2=0 \Rightarrow y_{n}=c\cdot(\dfrac 3 5)^n +1 \Rightarrow \\$

$x_{n}=\dfrac 6 5 +\dfrac 4 {5c\cdot (\dfrac 3 5 )^n+5}$

Now obviously

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }x_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac 6 5 +\dfrac 4 {5c\cdot (\dfrac 3 5 )^n+5}=\dfrac 6 5+\dfrac 4 5=2$